# AVAssetExportSession can't export for reason operation not support for media

Tags: ios, url, avfoundation

I want to export a `.mov` file with objective-c on ios device, here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //NSURL *videoUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"4a213c6f-d038-494c-bed2-07ed50aef5ac" withExtension:@"mov"];

    NSURL *videoUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://gamecdn.gifmiao.com/wallpaper/4a213c6f-d038-494c-bed2-07ed50aef5ac.mov"];

    AVURLAsset *assets = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:videoUrl options:nil];

    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:assets presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];

    NSURL *exportUrl = [[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory
                                                                inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"export.mov"];

    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    exportSession.outputURL = exportUrl;

    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{

        if(exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted){
            NSLog(@"export successfully at :%@", exportUrl);
        }else if(exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed){
            NSLog(@"export failed error is %@", [exportSession.error description]);
        }
    }];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

The problem is that when I build the `AVURLAsset` with a url which is a http link, the exporting will failed with error as:

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11838 "Operation Stopped" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The operation is not supported for this media., NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped, NSUnderlyingError=0x60400024b820 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12109 "(null)"}}
```

and this error poped out too:

```
Task <0F298017-8D66-4ADB-8D65-5656FD256DA4>.<2> finished with error - code: -999
```

But when I download the video file and put it in the resource of the main bundle (which is just drag and drop into the Xcode project) things will work fine.

Why is that and how to fix that?

Comment: problem with that video . it's not supported to play in safari . so only we are getting that error

Comment: am not sure. The video need to play in Safari will support and please cross check in Apple supported video types

Comment: @Vinodh but I just checked that the video is with a correct content type of `Content-Type: video/quicktime` and it could be played on fire with safari version `11.0.1`